# В AppMetrika можно посмотреть откуда было скачивание?

Tags: мобильные-приложения, маркетинг

Есть метрика для моб. приложений от Яндекса AppMetrica идут несколько рекламных кампаний и скачивания приложения из iTunes. Вопрос - можно ли посмотреть в AppMetrica источник откуда человек пришёл в магазин перед скачиванием и как вообще отслеживаются источники скачиваний в приложениях?

Comment: Поставь разные счетчики